# Calculation of $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\dfrac{e^{itx}}{x^2+1}\ dx$ using two different methods

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Consider the integral $$I=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \dfrac{e^{itx}}{x^2+1} dx$$ given that $t\geq0$.

Now, we take a semicircular contour in the upper half of the argand plane. It encloses the singularity $+i$. Making use of the Residue theorem we get-
$$I=2\pi i\ \lim_{z\rightarrow i}\dfrac{e^{itz}}{z+i}=\pi e^{-t}$$ which is the final and correct answer.

But if we open up the integral into sine and cosine parts, I see a problem. The sine part vanishes because of being an odd function. The integral then remains:
$$I=2\pi i\ \lim_{z\rightarrow +i} \dfrac{\cos{tz}}{z+i}=\dfrac{\pi}{2}(e^t+e^{-t})$$

The issue seems to be that we just can't make the second integral vanish. But I can't see how.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You cannot take that contour and just ignore the semicircle. The function you integrate has to die off at $o(1/r)$ to make that work.

Comment: Maybe a contribution of the arc remains in either the sine part or the cosine part or both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second integral, $cos z$ grows exponentially in magnitude. So the countour method doesn't work as you can't discard the semicircle part.

In the first one, choosing the upper half plane makes the function die off exponentially, so it works.

Comment: Thanks for the help.